# trying to change background img in JavaScript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

i want to change the background image of a div every 3 sec i tried this did not wark help plss.

it is not working...

i update the code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/x-icon" href="Main Images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyle.css" />
             <script>
                 accept
                 var rotate = false;

                 function setbackground() {
                     newImage = rotate ? 'url(#)' : 'url(mimages/wallpaper2.jpg) : url(mimages/shutterstock_105126044-795x380.jpg)';
                     rotate = !rotate;
                     document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
                 }

                 setInterval(setbackground, 3000);
</script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('Main Images/background.jpg');">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div dir="rtl" style="background-color:#242020">
        <audio src="songs/Jurassic Park Theme Song - Jurassic Park Theme Song.mp3" autoplay="" controls=""></audio><br /><br />
    </div>
        <div class="top" id="change" runat="server" >
```

Comment: Once `setbackground` is called, you're currently calling it again in 5 seconds. The biggest problem right now is that you don't seem to be calling it a first time, so the timeout is never set. Other than that, it's not quite clear what your `rotate` is supposed to be. You're alterating betweeh `background-image: url(#)` and an invalid property for `background-image` (seemingly specifying two images). Did you mean to alternate between the two images instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var rotate = false;

function setbackground() {
  newImage = rotate ? 'url(mimages/wallpaper2.jpg)' : 'url(mimages/shutterstock_105126044-795x380.jpg)';
  rotate = !rotate;
  document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}

setInterval(setbackground, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="top" id="change"></div>
```

Comment: should i write some thing in the div tag eighther

Comment: Your div should have attribute  id="change". then only this will work. @OzCohen

Comment: @OzCohen. Try the new code. And yeah Keep the <script></script> below the body. That way your javascript will always have access to the dom .

Comment: how can i do background-size:cover

Comment: document.getElementById("change").style.backgroundSize = "cover"; put that after setting the background image.

Comment: can i had more picture??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113145/discussion-between-oz-cohen-and-rishabh-dev).